# Source mapping in IE. //@ sourceURL

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, source-maps

In IE doesn't work //@ sourceURL.

```
appLoader.loadScriptContent(doc, scriptData.data + "//@ sourceURL=" + scriptData.url );
```

In Another browsers it's OK. How can I change this code for working in IE ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23134416/22227), IE11 supports //# sourceURL, which is also supported by recent Firefox & Chrome.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but IE does not support source mapping. It's not even IE11 (at least not in the IE11 preview, anyway).

It may come eventually, but for now the answer is you can't do it. Sorry.

That said, as of this moment, it's still an experimental feature even in the browsers that do support it, and is still subject to change -- for example, I note that the syntax is being changed from `//@` to `//#` in the nightlies, due to a clash with IE's existing JS conditional-comment syntax (`//@cc_on` etc).

Comment: And so...what should I do? :)

Comment: Nothing you can do. IE doesn't support it. If you want to debug in IE, you'll have to use the uncompressed source code for the time being. I'd be willing to bet they'll bring it in for IE12, but that's still some time away.

Comment: @JosephLust What do you mean Chrome and IE - specifically I care about what you mean about IE

Comment: @Wartickler please see http://blog.oio.de/2014/04/04/internet-explorer-11-source-map-based-debugging/

Comment: The part highlighted in yellow did not work for my jquery 1.11.2 in IE11. There is no option to see unminified files via Debugger in F12. Source maps work seamlessly in Firefox.

Answer (score 16):

With the latest update that came with Windows 8.1, IE11 now supports source map: https://all-markup-news.com/whats-new-in-f12-with-windows-8-1-update/
Works in Win7 as well.

Comment: It is useful for development debugging, but less useful for production, because IE does not put the sourceURL into the stack trace for the exception (whereas Chrome does).

Comment: Any idea how to *disable* it?